# how to identify the current subscription plan in in app purchase [auto renewal]

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have three subscription plans in `in-app-purchase` **1 month**,**6 months**,**1 year** so i want to check the users current **subscription** plan and *date of expire* so  what i am doing right now is from receipt getting `latest_receipt_info` in that I am using the last object.
from the last **object**, I am taking `product_id` and using it as a current **subscription** plan and `expires_date` used to check active or not.
Below is the block of `code` I am using.
So is this the correct approach?

```
if([dict[@"status"] integerValue] == 0) {
    if([dict.allKeys containsObject:@"latest_receipt_info"]) {
        NSArray *iapReceipts = dict[@"latest_receipt_info"];
        if(iapReceipts) {
            if(iapReceipts.count > 0) {
                NSDictionary *latestReceipt = [iapReceipts lastObject];
                if(latestReceipt) {
                    _currentIAPID = latestReceipt[@"product_id"];
                    NSDate *expireDate = latestReceipt[@"expires_date"];
                    if(expireDate) {
                        NSInteger days = DaysBetween(NSDate.date, expireDate);
                        if(days >= 0) {
                            NSLog(@"days %ld",(long)days);
                            status = SubscriptionStatusActive;

                        } else {
                            NSLog(@"Subs :NEGATIVE DAYS");
                            status = SubscriptionStatusExpired;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a correct approach. You shouldn't get last object because that array is not sorted. It contains all your transactions including all renewals. This example code doesn't take into account cancellation_date:

```
- (void)parseResponse:(NSDictionary*)dict{
    if ([dict[@"status"] integerValue] != 0) {return;}

    NSArray *iapReceipts = dict[@"latest_receipt_info"];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV";

    for (NSDictionary *iapReceipt in iapReceipts){
        NSString *productID = iapReceipt[@"product_id"];
        NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:iapReceipt[@"expires_date"]?:@""];

        if (date && [date timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]] > 0){
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:date forKey:productID];
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)isSubscriptionActive:(NSString*)productID {
    NSDate *date = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:productID];
    if (date && [date timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]] > 0){
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: The right way would be to use server side receipt validation. If you want to do it on the device, you need at least to also check that the `cancelationDate` property of the newest transaction is unset